# SVG Image Generate

Tags: php, html, svg

Have tried below code to generate SVG image

```
<path fill="transparent" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5"
            d="M15 3
               Q16.5 6.8 25 18
               A12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
               Q13.5 6.8 15 3z" />

    var pat = "M"+15+" "+3+" "+ "Q"+ 16.5 +" "+6.8+ " " + 25 + " " +18+ " "+"A" + 12.8 + " " + 12.8+ " " + 0 + " " + 1  + " " + 1 + " " + 5  + " " +18+ " " +"Q" + 13.5 + " " + 6.8 + " " + 15 + " " + 3 + "Z";

      e.append("path").attr("d", pat);
```

and got below image
[image]

But i need this image

[image]

What should i do to make it as same as second image.

Comment: scale it in the y axis using a transform.

Comment: Can you elaborate  your answer

Comment: What is it about the comment you don't understand?

Comment: d="M15 3
               Q16.5 6.8 25 18
               A12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
               Q13.5 6.8 15 3z"
In which section need to change please explain

Comment: None of it. Add a transform attribute to the path.

Comment: sorry, But we are not trying to transform the svg image, we just want to skew the image from top of the section.

Comment: Here is my ellipse code : <ellipse cx="497.5" cy="220" ry="187" rx="140" stroke="#f2f2f2" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" stroke-width="1"></ellipse> and i just want to make it shrink from top section as per the mentioned above image.

Comment: Add a transform attribute to the parts you want to change, or redraw the whole lot in an SVG editor.

Comment: Really appreciate your help Robert, Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many coordinates value i found the exact coordinate for creating drop svg

Here is the code:

```
<svg height="1010" width="500">
<path fill="transparent" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5"
        d="M297.5 3        
           Q297.5 6.8 410.5 150           
           A120.8 102.8 0 1 1 210 148           
           Q297.5 6.8 297.5 3z"       
           />
</svg>
```

Happy coding !!!